# Stripe Response Error when Charging Card in Testing environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stripe-payments

Stack: Angular, Node.js, Express, MongoDB
Using angular-stripe

When attempting to charge a test card i get this error

```
angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of null
    at config.js:688
    at processQueue (angular.js:15757)
    at angular.js:15773
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16841)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
    at done (angular.js:11454)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11652)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11593)
config.js:697 Other error occurred, possibly with your API Cannot read property 'amount' of null
```

Here is the code:

Node.js

```
app.post('/payment', function(req, res){
    var stripeToken = req.body.token;
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 19999, // amount in cents, again
        currency: "usd",
        source: stripeToken,
        description: "Example charge"
        }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
            console.log(err);// The card has been declined
        } else {
            res.send({
                success:true,
                data: charge
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Angular:

```
   $scope.stripeCallback = function (card) {
  return stripe.card.createToken(card)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log('token created for card ending in ', response.card.last4, response.id);
        var payment = response;
        payment.card = response.card;
        payment.token = response.id;
        console.log(payment);
        return $http.post('/payment', payment);
    })
    .then(function (payment) {
        console.log(payment);
        console.log('successfully submitted payment for $', payment.data.data.amount);
        $scope.successfulPayment = payment.data.data.amount;

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        if (err.type && /^Stripe/.test(err.type)) {
            $scope.unsuccessfulPayment('Stripe error: ', err.message);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Other error occurred, possibly with your API', err.message);
        }
    });
};
```

The Form:

```
    <form class="boxForm" name="checkoutForm" layout="column" layout-align="center center" stripe-form="stripeCallback">

        <md-input-container>
        <label>Card Number</label>
               <input type="text" ng-model="card.number" payments-format="card" payments-validate="card" payments-type-model="type"/>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
        <label>Expiry Month</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="card.exp_month"  payments-format="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" />
        </md-input-container>
        <label>Expiry year</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="card.exp_year"  payments-format="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" />
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
        <label>Card CVC</label>
             <input type="text" ng-model="card.cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type"/>  
        </md-input-container>
        <button ng-click="stripeCallback(card)" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

According to the error, its at line 688 so i've added a console.log for the $http response console.log(payment) at line 687 and it's obvious why. The server side response sends no data in the charge object despite having success. That said, i cannot seem to pass the data in from the server despite passing all required fields from the client (cvc, card, exp_month, exp_year, stripetoken) and a successful request. This code worked previously which baffles me even more. It seems on the server side the charge object passed into the async function is getting no data is the issue.

This shows the token created, on the request from the client before being passed to the server. Very confused,  Any help is appreciated.

```
token created for card ending in  4242 tok_18h90xHXm9b68JK2Enr7JT9Q
```

Comment: Doesn't `payment.data.data.amount` have to be `payment.data.amount`?